# how to add class inside a select tag

Tags: html, css

I have got the following sign up form but need to add line height only for the select tag and I thought it would be as easy as adding a class in each select tag as follows: I tried to do the following but it doesn't work...I thought that the following should work but can you have a class inside a select tag?.

```css
.signup-form .subscriptionplan {
  line-height: 90px;

}
```

```html
 <form class="signup-form" action="includes/signup2.php" method="POST">
         <label>First name</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="text" name="first"  placeholder="First Name">
         <br></br>
         <label>Last name</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="text" name="last"  placeholder="Last Name">
         <br></br>
         <label>E-Mail</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
         <br></br>
         <label>Username</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="User ID">
         <br></br>
         <label>Password</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
         <br></br>
         <label>Referral</label>
         <br></br>
         <input type="text" name="referral" placeholder="referral">
         <br></br>
         <label>Basic Subscription Plan</label>
         <br></br>
         <select name="freelesson">
            <option value="Primer Level">Primer Level: Free</option>
         </select>
         <br></br>
          <label>Premium Subscription Plan 1</label>
          <br></br>

         <select name="subscriptionplan" class="subscriptionplan">
            <option value="">Choose Subscription Plan 1</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>
            <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
            <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
         </select>
         <br></br>
         <select name="pricing_level1" class="subscriptionplan">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 1</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="100">Monthly:$100</option>
          <option value="800">Yearly:$800</option>
          </select>
        <br></br>
        <select name="pricing_level2" class="subscriptionplan">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 2</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="150">Monthly:$150</option>
          <option value="1300">Yearly:$1300</option>
          </select>
          <br></br>
          <select name="pricing_level3" class="subscriptionplan">
          <option value="">Choose a price plan for Level 3</option>
          <option value="None">None</option>
          <option value="200">Monthly:$200</option>
          <option value="1800">Yearly:$1800</option>
          </select>
         <br></br>
         <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
```

I can manage to get it to work if I add

```html
<div class="subscriptionplan"
```

before all the select tag but thought that I should be able to get this to work within the select tag? Can't I have a class within a class? Can I do .signup-form .subscriptionplan?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this is by putting an option with dashes and making it unselectable in between the options where you want a line.

```
<select name="subscriptionplan" class="subscriptionplan">
            <option value="">Choose Subscription Plan 1</option>
            <option value="None">None</option>
             <option disabled="disabled">-------</option>
            <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
            <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
            <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
         </select>
```

or you can use HTML UTF-8 box drawing light horizontal like-

```
<select name="subscriptionplan" class="subscriptionplan">
                <option value="">Choose Subscription Plan 1</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                 <option value="" disabled="disabled">&#9472;</option>
                <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
                <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
                <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
             </select>
```

or just copy paste this-

```
<select name="subscriptionplan" class="subscriptionplan">
                <option value="">Choose Subscription Plan 1</option>
                <option value="None">None</option>
                 <option value="" disabled="disabled">──────────────────</option>
                <option value="Level 1">Level 1</option>
                <option value="Level 2">Level 2</option>
                <option value="Level 3">Level 3</option>
             </select>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but my main problem is to get the class "subscriptionplan" to work and at the moment, css just doesn't seem to pick it up if i add a class inside the select tag but will only pick it up if I add a div class before it..I thought that it should work by doing .signup-form .subscriptionplan {}

Comment: what css you want to apply to the class subscriptionplan?

Comment: I have an overall class called signup-form, which is the class for the whole form but would like to add another class just for the select tags but not sure if this is possible? For some reason, I can only get it to work by adding another separate div class

Comment: So, should the above syntax work or must I need a div class? Can i do..

Comment: <select name="subscriptionplan" class="subscriptionplan">

Comment: So, I guess it depends on what I am trying to achieve correct? If I put a class in a div class before the form attribute, then I would apply styling to the whole form? but am still wondering why it won't work if I put it within the select tag? thanks!

Comment: Try adding the select tag in a div and then you can apply any CSS to that div.